# eclipse-dynamic web project missing

Tags: eclipse, servlets

I installed **Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers** on my laptop and could not find the dynamic web project option in **file/new/**

Does anyone know how this can be fixed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It will be found under new/project/  then you can choose what kind of project you wanna create.

Comment: You're running with at least Java 6, right?

Comment: It will be found under: `NEW -> Web -> Dynamic Web Project`.

Answer (score 0):

You may find it in the following location :

> File > new > other > expand web folder > there should be a dynamic web project

hope that my answer is helpful.